# How to solve $\int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4{\cos}^2t+9{\sin}^2t}dt$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4{\cos}^2t+9{\sin}^2t}dt$$

Using trigonometric identity, I changed to $\frac{1}{4+5{\sin}^2t}$

Then I'm lost..

what should I do to solve this question?

Comment: make the substitution $t=\arctan(u)$

Comment: You can compute this using the residue formula in complex analysis.

Comment: @DamianRössler that'll be an overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{4 \cos ^2 t+9 \sin ^2 t} d t &=4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 t}{4+9 \tan ^2 t} d t \\
&=4 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d y}{2^2+(3 y)^2},\quad \textrm{ where }y=\tan t \\
&=\frac{4}{6}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 y}{2}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x$
$$\int\frac{1}{5\sin^2 x+4}dx$$
$\displaystyle\sin x=\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}$
$$=\int\sec^2 x\cdot\frac{1}{9\tan^2 x+4}dx$$
Do $u=\tan x\implies\displaystyle\frac{du}{dx}=\sec^2 x$
$$=\int\frac{1}{9u^2+4}du$$
Do $\displaystyle v=\frac{3u}{2}\implies\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{3}{2}$
$$=\int\frac{2}{3(4v^2+4)}dv$$
$$=\int\frac16\frac{1}{v^2+1}dv$$
$$=\frac{\arctan v}{6}$$
$$=\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{3\tan\left(x\right)}{2}\right)}{6}$$
$$\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{3\tan\left(2\pi\right)}{2}\right)}{6}-\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{3\tan\left(0\right)}{2}\right)}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$